# can't log in to eclipse google plugin

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

when developing a google app engine project i suddenly can't login with my google acount.
here is the error:

```
 Error
    Sun Sep 25 18:03:11 CST 2011
    Could not sign in. Check that your computer's date and time are correct; sign-in errors can occur if your computer's time is significantly different from the server's time.
```

i am using eclipse 3.7 64bit with google plugin, my os is windows8 developer preview 64 bit.

i also tried eclipse 3.7 32bit on a win7 32bit machine, same problem. i don't think there is any problem with my time setting, does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the time of your computer's clock when you posted this, your clock is off by 12 hours.  Try switching PM for AM.  If both of your computers have this problem, maybe it's the company NTP server?

Comment: i am in China so i don't think it is wrong time, now i use a proxy with eclipse and then it works fine, haven't figure out why.

Comment: I wonder if your computer thinks CST is "China Standard Time" or "Central Standard Time."  The proxy probably has a clock that's correctly set, which would explain why it's working.